# Background can be seen through objects, Alpha Over doesn't work?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, node-editor

I made another post for this earlier but I didn't exactly explain it well enough. On the render, you can see the stars and such behind the planet, as if it's transparent. I tried using the Alpha Over node in Composition like I was told but it didn't work. I was re-directed to another post but
it wasn't really the same thing. My background is another layer and such, as shown in the bottom left. I can't get it to appear in the above so I can connect it to Alpha Over and it won't let me add one to its node editor.

The bottom right is the planets texture and the top is just more detail onto it

[image: Render]

[image: The Nodes]

Here's the link to the file https://www.dropbox.com/s/m032wc3pg66a7wv/Game.blend?dl=0

Comment: If your didn't get satisfactory answers, please edit the original question to clarify your intentions instead of duplicating your post. Also, the images posted on this question are very low res. It's hard to read the nodes. Making your file available with some explanation of the elements you are using would be the fastest way to get your issue resolved.

Comment: @cegaton Sorry, I'm new to this forum. It said on the other post how I have to continue through chat as comments were getting too long and for some reason it it said I wasn't high enough? Also it said that the question was already answered so I was confused on whether I could still add to that post or not. Sorry about the screenshot, when I get ahold of a computer I'll post the file. Also, I'm using cycles render with "noise" as stars. The tutorial I was following did it

Comment: Let's continue this in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34814/cegaton-and-whoever-wants-to-join)

Comment: It says that it's read only and I need 20 reputation. In about 30 min,  I'll be able to fix the screen shots. Since I can only post 2 on here, I can instead post a link to an Imgur album of multiple images with better resolution

Answer (score 4):

You just missed to check "transparent" in the render panel, under the film section.
Once you do that, your two renderlayers will have their own alpha channels and you will be able to composite them.

However, you'll notice that you no longer have the sky background. To bring it back you just need to turn the environment pass on in the planet render layer, and use it as background for your two plates.

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what's going on, so I'm just gonna go ahead and take a stab at it... we'll see whether my risk pays off or not ;-)

I'm not convinced that you're seeing what you think you're seeing. I'll bet that you're using the Cycles renderer. Furthermore, I'll bet that the "stars" you're seeing "through" the moon is actually [noise](https://www.blender.org/manual/render/cycles/reducing_noise.html) that is the result of too few samples.

To test this, replace your stars background with a checkerboard or some other non-spots background. I'll bet the checkerboard (or whatever) does not show through, and the "stars" are still there. This would indicate that it's *not* transparent, and the noise just happen to look like the stars you're using.

If this is true, the solution is to render more samples, or be more selective about which samples you're rendering (with branched path tracing). There are also other more specialized and more sophisticated noise reduction techniques that may be worth looking into.

I hope that helps!

Comment: The stars are noise I added using nodes. I've increased the samples, to the point of tripling it, yet it doesn't fix it.

Comment: well darn, I guess I'll have to guess again ;-)

Comment: If it helps, I used this tutorial for it https://youtu.be/9vbq6HOgA2w Sorry that I'm not much of a help, pretty much everything I've done so far is through a tutorial as I have no idea what I'm doing

Answer (score 0):

Guess #2!!

Try reversing the inputs of your Alpha Over. It's possible that your stars are going on top of your moon, and the "black" is alpha.

If that's the case, it'd certainly look the way it does, but without being able to see your nodes (images are small), it's hard to tell for sure.

Comment: Sorry, I split it up into 3 albums, the first being of the nodes within Composition imgur.com/a/bHSkH This is the nodes for the planets texture imgur.com/5wo5xd8 and here's the background aka stars imgur.com/a/h4RAg It only let me put 2 images on here so I was pretty limited. But I'll try reversing the Alpha Overs and see what happens

Comment: Oh my... that's a really complex setup. For starters, only swap the slots on the VERY FIRST Alpha Over, the one that combines the two render layers. If that doesn't fix it, then it'll take some more intense digging.

Comment: It didn't change anything http://imgur.com/a/uIpyZ I got the file link here, that might be easier though I don't know if the planet texture will be missing in that or not. https://www.dropbox.com/s/m032wc3pg66a7wv/Game.blend?dl=0 Here's the texture I used just in case http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_9DvzmslTIME/TQrT5bEDbII/AAAAAAAAAi4/q0jL2oQ_4rk/s1600/planet_Trask1200.png

Comment: Fascinating....

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I mean that I'm flummoxed as to what the problem might be. Even if that wasn't the problem, swapping the inputs should have at least done something crazy like make one of them disappear. Just for giggles, you might set up two File Output nodes to save the two images you're compositing together. Take a real close look at them and see if maybe there's something that's transparent that shouldn't be.

Comment: Ok I'll try that. Also, somebody suggested using an environment socket on the render layers and connect it to the Alpha Over. That didn't work but I'm wondering if I even did it correctly. As the noise is under the world nodes, is there a way to connect it through composition? If I need to, I can replace the atmosphere render layer with something else. Also I forgot what I did but I I did something earlier that ended the entire render being completely white earlier. I'll see if I can retrace what I did

Comment: If the stars are ONLY in the World nodes, then the ONLY possibility is that your moon, or some part of that layer is transparent... I'll have to investigate later...

Comment: So I deleted the Texture Coordinate in my planet nodes and other than it turning grey, I noticed that it no longer had that transparency to it. So that kinda fixed the problem but then I no longer had the texture. http://imgur.com/a/OOpnY

Comment: Yeah, I'll bet you a whole lot of... something, that your texture is introducing some kind of transparency. I'll try to remember to take a look at your file this evening and see what I can find.

Comment: Thank you. I might be using the wrong socket (using generated) in the Texture Coordinate because I've tried using different textures but same problem. Maybe it's doing this because I'm using a texture in general but I don't see why

Comment: ...this is going to take quite a bit of explaining. Let's move this to a BlenderArtists forum.

Comment: Here's the forum where we can discuss a bit more freely: http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?399159-Migrated-explanation-for-TitanJedi-from-Blender-SE&p=3051508#post3051508

Comment: I discovered that it is not caused by the background. Upon deleting the noise (stars) in background, the noise that appeared in the transparency of the planet remained so I've narrowed that out of it. I was thinking it could be something about texturing or perhaps lighting?

Comment: That's possible, but I'm pretty sure it's the compositing setup. Can you go to the forum post linked above and send me the image texture you're using for the moon?

Comment: Ok I did, It just says that I need a moderator to approve it.

Comment: Moderator approval to reply to the post?